# Repeat rows by pattern matching and removing pattern of the string

Tags: r, gsub

I have a table similar to this:

| Sequence | Modification | Modified.Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDEF | Acetyl (Protein N-term),Oxidation (M),Methyl (KR) | AB(Acetyl (Protein N-term))CD(Oxidation (M))EF(Methyl (KR)) |
| ABCDEFGH | Oxidation (M) | ABCDEF(Oxidation (M))GH |
| DEFGH | Acetyl (Protein N-term), Methyl (KR) | ABC(Acetyl (Protein N-term))DEF(Methyl (KR))GH |

I need to have only one Modification per row. For that I have to repeat the sequence N number of times, being N the number of modifications of that sequence. And Subtract the modification from the Modified Sequence.

This would be the expected:

| Sequence | Modification | Modified.Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABCDEF | Acetyl (Protein N-term) | AB(Acetyl (Protein N-term))CDEF |
| ABCDEF | Oxidation (M) | ABCD(Oxidation (M))EF |
| ABCDEF | Methyl (KR) | ABCDEF(Methyl (KR)) |
| ABCDEFGH | Oxidation (M) | ABCDEF(Oxidation (M))GH |
| DEFGH | Acetyl (Protein N-term) | ABC(Acetyl (Protein N-term))DEFGH |
| DEFGH | Methyl (KR) | ABCDEF(Methyl (KR))GH |

```
df = data.frame(
        Sequence = c('ABCDEF','ABCDEFGH','DEFGH'),
        Modification = c('Acetyl (Protein N-term),Oxidation (M),Methyl (KR)','Oxidation (M)','Acetyl (Protein N-term), Methyl (KR)'),
        Modified.Sequence = c('AB(Acetyl (Protein N-term))CD(Oxidation (M))EF(Methyl (KR))','ABCDEF(Mod3))GH',
        'ABC(Acetyl (Protein N-term))DEF(Methyl (KR))GH')
)
```

The modifications can be more than the ones in this reprex.

Comment: I'm trying to, SO doesn't let me add the edits ...

Comment: @akrun Kinda solved. Getting error if I don't add the ``` ``` around the table

Comment: The subtraction part is not clear.  The first part you can do with `library(tidyr);library(dplyr);df %>% separate_rows(Modification, Modified.Sequence, sep = ",\\s*|(?<=\\))(?=[A-Z]+\\()")`

Comment: Thanks @akrun is it clear now the subtraction part?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(Modification, sep = ",\\s?") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Mod = parse_number(Modification), 
         Modified.Sequence = map2_chr(Mod, Modified.Sequence, ~ gsub(paste0("\\(Mod\\s+\\([^", .x, "]\\)\\)"), 
                                                 "", .y))) %>%
  select(!Mod)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  Sequence Modification Modified.Sequence
  <chr>    <chr>        <chr>            
1 ABCDEF   Mod (1)      AB(Mod (1))CDEF  
2 ABCDEF   Mod (3)      ABCD(Mod (3))EF  
3 ABCDEF   Mod (2)      ABCDEF(Mod (2))  
4 ABCDEFGH Mod (3)      ABCDEF(Mod3))GH  
5 DEFGH    Mod (1)      ABC(Mod (1))DEFGH
6 DEFGH    Mod (2)      ABCDEF(Mod (2))GH
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @anoushiravan-r . Though , your answer is very specific to the reproducible example and I can't extrapolate it to my real dataset. I will edit the example now.

Comment: Yeah just put a more generalizable sample data and I will edit my answer as soon as I get some free time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my own question, though there's probably a cleaner way:

```
df <-  df %>% tidyr::separate_rows(Modification, sep =  ',\\s?')

for (ii in seq_len(nrow(df))) {

# Obtain the total modifications and add parenthesis:
    Modifications <- paste0('(',unique(df$Modification), ')')

# Modifications to remove, is the list of modifications without the
# corresponding modification of that sequence

    modsToRemove <- Modifications[! Modifications %in%
                     paste0('(',df$Modification[ii],')')]


# Add back slash to the parentheses
    modsToRemove <- gsub(pattern = '\\(', replacement = '\\\\(', modsToRemove)

    modsToRemove <- gsub(pattern = '\\)', replacement = '\\\\)', modsToRemove)

# Collapse the modifications to remove together to make it regex pattern

    modsToRemove <- paste(unlist(modsToRemove), collapse = '|')

# Remove all the modifications for the modified sequence (except the one)
# that is in the modifiedPeptides$Modification

    df$Modified.sequence[ii] <- gsub(pattern = modsToRemove,'',
                                       x = df$Modified.sequence[ii] )
    }
```